# Show the loader above all the elements

Tags: css, loader

I want to make this loader to be shown on a white background above all the elements on the site. Curently it is shown with transparency along with the menu and the logo
This is the website: https://lea.oranjuice.club/

This the css i've used for the loader

```
.loader {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url('https://lea.oranjuice.club/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/LeaSite_IntroAnimation270.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your `header` some z-index too, which will show it under your loader.

```
.header-absolute header.main-header {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 20 }
```